# Updating the same elements efficiently via JS

Tags: javascript, dom, foreach

Say I have a page containing multilple `LI` elements and stored them in an array:

```
 const listItems = document.querySelectorAll('li')
```

Now I want to update all those LI with `active` class, one approach could look like this:

```
const activeLIs = listItems.filter(item => item.classList.contains('active'))
activeLIs.forEach(activeLI => activeLI.classList.add('new-class'))
```

Problem is this the page could have hundreds of list items and could affect performance since this is hitting the DOM on each loop. Is there a better way to update the items like for example joining or storing them in an array? Just can't get the idea of distributing them back on the DOM with different `divs/container` once they're stored.

Comment: instead of `'li'` use `'li.active'` as your selector

Comment: If you use [`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) - for example `let activeElements = document.getElementsByClassName('active');` -  the browser will maintain a live HTMLCollection of the elements that have that particular class-name, finding a specific element will require searching within that collection though.

Comment: it is better to use `querySelectorAll` for loops instead of `getElementsByClassName()` for that reason

Comment: yes it helps but I think it doesn't matter how or what approach I use on getting the active elements (as it was just a scenario to have a list of elements on the page we will be updating). Main problem is how I add the "new class" to each active elements without using loop as you can see on the last line of the code. I think it is not good to hit the DOM on each loop, are there any better approach?

Comment: What do you mean by "hitting the DOM"? If you want to update multiple elements, you're going to have to iterate through all those elements. That's one reason why `querySelectorAll()` is better: it allows you to be more specific with your selector, while `getElementsByClassName()` only allows you to search for one class at a time.

Comment: Thanks @mykaf. I just thought there were better and other approach to update it that won't need to iterate on each item/loop.